# Agregar objetos con atributos a un array

Tags: java

Tengo un array(catalogo) con elementos dentro(articulos), esos elementos tienen varios atributos. (marca, precio, etc)

Necesito hacer un código que seleccionando la opción 1, te deje cargar elementos al catalogo, permitiendo colocar marca, precio, etc del mismo. Tengo entendido que es con el .add pero no se como escribirlo correctamente ni como hacer para que se puedan ingresar los atributos del elemento nuevo. Muchas gracias!

```
//Instancio y cargo articulos
    articulos coca = new articulos("Coca-Cola",0, 146781, 90, 10);
    articulos papas = new articulos("PapasFritas",1, 817540, 80, 10);
    articulos patys = new articulos("Patys",2, 574395, 130, 10);
    articulos agua = new articulos("Botella-Agua",3, 912378, 50, 10);
    articulos cafe = new articulos("Cafe",4, 489517, 70, 10);
    
    //instancio el array
    articulos catalogo[] = new articulos[articulos.dimensionArray];
    
    //relleno el catalogo con los objetos
    catalogo[0] = coca;
    catalogo[1] = papas;
    catalogo[2] = patys;
    catalogo[3] = agua;
    catalogo[4] = cafe;
```

este es mi método para imprimir la información:

```
public void listaArticulos(articulos catalogo[]) {
    
    Scanner scanart = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("LISTA DE ARTICULOS----------");
    gestion.mostrarArticulos(catalogo);
    System.out.println("\nQue desea hacer? \n\n1-Cargar articulos\n2-Editar articulos\n3-Eliminar articulos\n4-Salir");
    int scanartvar = scanart.nextInt();
    
        switch(scanartvar) {
            case 1 : System.out.println("");
            articulos.add(new articulo); //aqui deberia ir  el codigo de cargar articulos
            
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes un `ArrayList` de objetos `articulos` puedes enviar esa información a tu método e imprimir la información.

```
   public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<articulos> listaArticulos = new ArrayList<articulos>();
        
        //Instancio y cargo articulos
        articulos coca = new articulos("Coca-Cola", 0, 146781, 90, 10);
        listaArticulos.add(coca);
        articulos papas = new articulos("PapasFritas", 1, 817540, 80, 10);
        listaArticulos.add(papas);
        articulos patys = new articulos("Patys", 2, 574395, 130, 10);
        listaArticulos.add(patys);
        articulos agua = new articulos("Botella-Agua", 3, 912378, 50, 10);
        listaArticulos.add(agua);
        articulos cafe = new articulos("Cafe", 4, 489517, 70, 10);
        listaArticulos.add(cafe);

        /* //instancio el array
    articulos catalogo[] = new articulos[articulos.dimensionArray];
    
    //relleno el catalogo con los objetos
    catalogo[0] = coca;
    catalogo[1] = papas;
    catalogo[2] = patys;
    catalogo[3] = agua;
    catalogo[4] = cafe;*/
        
     listaArticulos(listaArticulos);   
        
    }
```

Te sugiero uses el `ArrayList` de objetos articulos para que realices tus operaciones.

```
    public static void listaArticulos( List<articulos> listaArticulos) {
        
         Scanner scanart = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("LISTA DE ARTICULOS----------");
        //gestion.mostrarArticulos(catalogo);
        System.out.println("\nQue desea hacer? \n\n1-Cargar articulos\n2-Editar articulos\n3-Eliminar articulos\n4-Salir");
        int scanartvar = scanart.nextInt();

        switch (scanartvar) {
            case 1:
                for(articulos art: listaArticulos){                   
                    System.out.println("nombre : " + art.getNombre());                 
                }

        }
        
    }
```